# Ubuntu 12.10 (32bit) System heatup

Tags: 12.10, ati, hp, overheating

I'm using HP envy 4
intel i5 3rd gen, 4GB ram, 2GB ATI Raedon 7670M graphics card.
freshly installed Ubuntu 12.10 (32bit) in my laptop used to turn off within 20 minutes due to overheating.
i followed up similar posts and installed an AMD graphics driver. 
[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/126513#126513)
after following the above post i my system would turn off less often due to overheating, but whenever my system heated up, which it did roughly after half an hour, all my programs gets hanged.
what do i do??

Comment: Why do you use Ubuntu 32-bit?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the ATI drivers is one thing but remember both graphics cards are still running together which is heating up your system so you need to switch one off to save heat and energy...  Try this link and see if any of the solutions work: http://mschoofs.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/switch-off-ati-vga-in-hybrid-cards-with.html

Also, you could try a lighter desktop environment other than Unity to save on graphics card use, maybe Xubuntu (XFCE)...